# How to get the Customer Group binded to a Sale rule in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've got a Shopping Cart Price Rule allowed for one Customer Group.

How can I get this Customer Group id programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to retrieve customer id which is allowed for customer group.

```
$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();
 foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
        $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($rule->getId());
        $customer_ids = $rule->getData('customer_group_ids'); 
    }
 }
```

You will have customer group id array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $rule->getData('customer_group_ids') I would recommend to use $rule->getCustomerGroupIds().

In CE 1.8 "salesrule_customer_group" is a separate table and the class Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule has an own function getCustomerGroupIds() to retrieve the customer group ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer group ids by using Dependency Injection:

```
protected $_customerGroupIds;

public function __construct(

         ..........
         ........
         \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupIds,
         ..... 
) {

         $this->_customerGroupIds = $customerGroupIds; 
}

public function getCustomerGroupIds() 
{  

         $groupIds = $this->_customerGroupIds->addFieldToSelect('customer_group_id')- 
         >getData(); //Currently you are getting data as a multidimensional array.

         //Now I am converting this into single array
         $customerGroupIdsSingleArray = [];
         foreach($customerGroupIdsSingleArray as $childArray)
         {
            foreach ($childArray as $value) 
             { 
              $customerGroupIdsSingleArray[] = $value; 
             } 
         }
         $groupIds = array_values($customerGroupIdsSingleArray);

         return $groupIds;


}
```